# FTOC and Path Integration

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the straight line with starting point $-i$ and final point $1$. I have parametrised this to get $\gamma (t) = -i+t+it$

I want to compute $\int z   dz$ around this path.

I have used path integration to get the answer of $2+2i$ which I'm pretty sure is correct.

I want to now calculate this integral using only the fundamental theorem of calculus. Either I'm using the FTOC wrong or something else has gone wrong because I cannot get the answers the same.

If someone could show me how to calculate this integral using the FTOC, that'd be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antiderivative of the analytic function $f(z)=z$ is $z^2$. Therefore, we have

$$\int_{-i}^1 z\,dz=\frac12((1)^2-(-i)^2)=1$$

Using the parametric description $z=-i+(1+i)t$ such that $dz=(1+i)\,dt$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-i}^1 z\,dz&=\int_0^1 \underbrace{\left(-i+(1+i)t\right)}_{=z}\,\underbrace{(1+i)\,dt}_{dz}\\\\
&=(1-i)+\frac12(1+i)^2\\\\
&=(1-i)+\frac12(2i)\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: ah, I didn't convert my limits. I was integrating between $-i$ to $1$ w.r.t $t$ and not between $0$ and $1$. thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with your answer for the integral. I find the answer 1.
Rather than do the question for you I prefer to give you hints so that you can find the answer yourself.

Hints:

1. $dz = (1 + i)dt$.
2. What do you thus get for $z\,dz$?
3. You must convert your integration bounds for $z$ to integration bounds for $t$ - what do you use?
4. You haven't told us what you find using the fundamental theorem of calculus...

Comment: Yes, I didn't convert my integration bounds but now I have. Thanks!